# Problem with php and file_get_contents , allow_url_fopen

Tags: php, file, url, file-get-contents

I have this code

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOSAcpFJwy?indent=2");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$tama_array=sizeof($json_a);
print $tama_array;
?>
```

i compile in my computer but dont work . I have allow_url_fopen=On . So i dont know why not work

This is error:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOSAcpFJwy?indent=2): in D:\repositorio\json\koha-banner\pruebajson.php on line 2
0

Comment: code works for me locally

Comment: The error message looks like something is missing (the actual error description to be precise). Are you sure this is the complete error message?

Comment: Yes that is complete error, so what additional i need configure, because it´s works in other computer.